# How to use a .vapi file from an library in a program that compiles with cmake?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vala

I'm trying to incorporate Grilo into someone else's existing project that compiles with cmake.  This seems like it should be simple but I've been digging for hours. I downloaded libgrilo-0.2-dev on Ubuntu. It contains

```
/usr/share/vala/vapi/grilo-0.2.vapi and /usr/share/vala/vapi/grilo-net-0.2.vapi
```

I added libgrilo-0.2 to DEPS_PACKAGES and find_packages in the CMakeLists file. No errors there. I added

```
using Grilo;
```

And that prevents the project from compiling. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out its just a matter of naming things correctly. grilo-0.2 needs to go in the CMakeLists.txt file.

```
using Grl;
```

is what needs to be put in the code.